# How do log.dir and log.dirs broker properties differ?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run a Kafka cluster with each broker using multiple log dirs (my servers use a JBOD disk setup). To achieve this, I set `log.dirs=/log1,/log2,/log3, etc.`, a simple comma-separated list of log directories, in broker's `server.properties` configuration file.

Having read the documentation I started wondering what is the purpose of the `log.dir` (singular, no `s` at the end) property which always takes the default value of `/tmp/kafka-logs`. How these two should be used in a broker which stores logs in many directories? I would expect that `log.dirs` takes a precedence over `log.dir` but the docs do not confirm this explicitly: https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation.html#brokerconfigs_log.dir. It says `log.dir` is supplemental to `log.dirs`.

Also, when removing the `log.dir` property from the broker (and using only `log.dirs`), during Kafka startup, the `log.dir` property is actually set to `/tmp/kafka-logs`, the default value (I see it in the `server.log`) but the directory is never created in the filesystem and logs are stored in `log.dirs`.

Happy to hear from people running brokers with a JBOD setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the docs do not confirm this explicitly:

Yes, they do

> > log.dirs - If not set, the value in log.dir is used

This implies the default value of log.dir doesn't matter. It's never used as long as log.dirs is set, which itself can also use one directory, if needed

Both properties are kept for backwards compatibility, and I suspect log.dir may eventually be deprecated and removed

Comment: "The default value of log.dir doesn't matter. It's never used as long as log.dirs is set" - aha, in that case it is now clear. I wish the docs stated this explicitly.